# Line Rendere Default Pink Color still Visible

Tags: unity, rendering

I am using the line Renderer for shooting in my game. Everything works well except for the fact that the default pink color is still visible. I have a Material set, so I do not think it is a problem of materials lacking. Someone Help please.

[image: LineRenderer Material I use]

[image: Line Renderer Configuration]

Comment: Worth noting also is that I added a light component to the Gameoject (gameobject here is the tip of the gun barrel)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue with the information you've presented. Setting up a LineRenderer with an Unlit Color shader material displays the selected colour as expected. Things you can try: 1. Close Unity & delete your Library folder, then re-open to force Unity to re-bake all its assets - this can solve issues with corrupted files. 2. Double-check that there's not a second renderer in your scene that's the actual source of the problem. 3. Try to reproduce the problem in a new, empty project and record your steps.